# careers.stackoverflow.com blocked

Tags: discussion, jobs, firewall

careers.stackoverflow.com is now categorized as Job Search by BlueCoat, and therefore is blocked at my job site.

Comment: oh yeah, gravatars are blocked here! My company has blocked little icons!

Comment: And who cares?...

Comment: Would you rather they classify it as adult-entertainment?

Comment: @George IV that just started for us yesterday. Apparently after years of use, gravatar is now "network storage and backup"

Comment: ...and what's your question?

Comment: @George- my company does not block the gravatars, but does log them at "non-business related web surfing". Each "non-business" http request counts against a total allowed amount of time, and if you do that too much your internet is cut off.  Too many cut offs and you get to have a chat with HR.  I ended up having to manually block Gravatar on my local machine.

Comment: Rex M: Your company uses WebSense, doesn't it? So does mine, and it started yesterday.

Comment: As fun as it sounds to have the careers.stackoverflow.com site blocked, how about having the jQuery files hosted by Google blocked by firewalls....

Comment: you guys need a new job! just go to careers.stack.. oh.

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately, that sounds like the correct categorization.  If your employer wants to block job search sites, that's (literally) their business.  It's probably a bad idea, but it's still their decision to make.

Comment: This = the answer.

Answer (score 11):

Hey, look on the bright side: if you needed any more proof that it's time to find a new job...

Answer (score 5):

use ssh's dynamic proxy option ssh -D my.home.computer -D 1080 to forward your connections through your home system. then set firefox to use localhose:1080 as a proxy server.
then find a job that doesnt require such hoops in order to find a better one.

Comment: why not directly go for the "better one" rather than look for the intermediate job without the blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Well...it is a job search site...what do you expect us to do?

Comment: Nothing - until my question was edited, I was just pointing out that BlueCoat now categorizes it as Job Search and so more employers who automatically block that category will block it for people.