# Is there a way to change the "submit edition" link, once generated?

Tags: support

Here comes a strange question.

When I want to edit one answer in particular, the link for the "Save your edits", obviously randomly generated, contains amongst other random characters the following word: **babe**.

**Edit: screenshot to show the link:**

[screenshot-link http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/3962/editlink.jpg](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/3962/editlink.jpg)

Nothing wrong in itself, it's randomly generated, and not really offensive. however, it was deemed offensive by my workplace's proxy, which refuses to send my request (and probably notified the local admin that I'm trying to watch some things that I'm not...)

**Question is: is there a way for me to change this link, is it related to my current session, or is it a strong link, and will remain the same for this particular question?**

Comment: random, what are you doing here? Bad boy!

Comment: Where are you seeing these babes?

Comment: What a canting question, random. You can't fool us!

Comment: Not sure where you're seeing these babes, do you have a properly marked out screenshot to illustrate?

Comment: A screenshot with babes shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Comment: Sounds like the other half of this sordid tale: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28399/careers-blocked-no-free-throw

Comment: Solution: Get rid of your workplace's content filtering. You're really missing out on good content. I bet you can't even read my magnificent profile. It's really awesome. Really.

Comment: You could even ask a question on SU: "How to circumvent my workplace's content filter?"

Comment: He could but then there'd be comments about how it's so wrong subverting The Man and his policies and to not fight the system and just roll with it or quit and find a better job. Because when The Man lays down the rules, you gotta stick by them with a clenched body part. Or just spend another day on reddit.

Comment: @random: He'd only get a reply like that if Atwood would happen to be online at that time.

Comment: Atwood is always online. He never sleeps. Not to mention his army of archangels out there.

Comment: He is a vampire. Vampires don't have armies of archangels. The best they have is one vampire who happens to be ironically named Angel. He's not an angel, either: he's just a guy in a vampire suit. And a leather jacket.

Comment: @I'm-really-awesome : Actually, it's really silly, it filters only urls, not content. So yes, I was able to bask in the awesomeness of your profile :-]

Comment: @Gnoupi: you are not here for reading profiles, you are here for providing screenshots! Do your work!

Comment: @Am I really Welbog: I know he's a vampire. I said that. He does not sleep.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, though. It's an actual question, even if some people made it a comment-fest. But I guess waiting for people to explain downvotes is vain.

Comment: Downvote was because it took you a while to point out where the link you're talking about actually was.

Comment: I said that it was the link for "save your edits". And all comments suggesting to post a screenshot seemed more "for fun" than actual requests, yesterday.

Comment: "Not sure where you're seeing these babes, do you have a properly marked out screenshot to illustrate?" was quite plainly put. And to see on your version what looks like a luck of the random hash draw.

Comment: @random: I thought I said that in my original message ("the link for the "Save your edits", obviously randomly generated, contains amongst other random characters the following word: babe."), but obviously I need to improve my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What a babe! ;)

It looks much like a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) to me. I assume Jeff uses them to [distinguish the different edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28629/was-int-or-guid-used-as-the-primary-key-index-in-stackoverflow-and-why/28676#28676) easily.

It's not just your session:

[image: leg shot of the babe link]

Comment: Ok, so in this case, it would be linked to each edit, not to the account, I guess.

Comment: Nope, no harem for you ;) They are linked to the edits.

Comment: Aaaaahhh! Jeff, why can't I upvote my own post? - Lovely, random :)