# Was int or guid used as the primary key/index in StackOverflow, and why?

Tags: discussion, openid, authentication

Given Jeff's post here http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000817.html, which type of user id was used in the site.

I presume it was int, as it is used in the URL, and as far as I can see there is not the need to use GUID, as the benefits in the above are for distributed disconnected systems, it seems to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the data dump, it is an integer.

Comment: Likely a `bigint`.

Comment: @voyager: That is not the question.

Answer (score 3):

post revisions use guids, but everything else is standard incrementing integers